# Call to undefined function Drupal\Component\Utility\imagecreate()

Tags: 8

I got this error on a server I setup and was confused:

> Error: Call to undefined function Drupal\Component\Utility\imagecreate() in Drupal\Component\Utility\Random->image() (line 282 of /var/lib/jenkins/src/grls/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Random.php

Answer (score 2):

The imagecreate function is part of php's gd library. If a server has been set up manually it's possible it doesn't have the gd library.

First, figure out which version of php you are using, for example with this command:

`dpkg -l | grep '^ii' | grep php`

Look for a line like:

```
ii  php7.2     7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2           all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
```

That indicates the server is using php7.2. To install gd library for php7.2 on a system managed with apt you need a command something like:

`sudo apt install php7.2-gd`

And then the error will be gone.